# PHP error on file upload

Tags: php, upload, header

I keep recieving a PHP error, "Call to undefined function getallheaders() in /home/jbird11/public_html/grids/upload.php on line 8"

The upload script basically takes an image that is dragged into an area, and uploads it. When I drag the image, I get this message.

Here is the first 40 or so lines of the php file:

```
 <?php

    // Maximum file size
    $maxsize = 1024; //Kb
    // Supporting image file types
    $types = Array('image/png','images/gif','image/jpeg');

    $headers = getallheaders();

    // LOG
    $log = '=== '. @date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' ========================================'."\n"
            .'HEADER:'.print_r($headers,1)."\n"
            .'GET:'.print_r($_GET,1)."\n"
            .'POST:'.print_r($_POST,1)."\n"
            .'REQUEST:'.print_r($_REQUEST,1)."\n"
            .'FILES:'.print_r($_FILES,1)."\n";
    $fp = fopen('log.txt','a');
    fwrite($fp, $log);
    fclose($fp);

    header('content-type: plain/text');

    // File size control
    if($headers['X-File-Size'] > ($maxsize *1024)) {
        die("Max file size: $maxsize Kb");
    }

// File type control
if(in_array($headers['X-File-Type'],$types)){
    // Create an unique file name
    $filename = sha1(@date('U').'-'.$headers['X-File-Name']).'.'.$_GET['type'];
    // Uploaded file source
    $source = file_get_contents('php://input');
    // Image resize
    imageresize($source, $filename, $_GET['width'], $_GET['height'], $_GET['crop'], $_GET['quality']);
} else die("Unsupported file type: ".$headers['X-File-Type']);

// File path
$path = str_replace('upload.php','',$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
// Image tag
echo '<img src="'.$path.$filename.'" alt="image" />';
```

Any idea what is causing this error? Permissions perhaps? Permission are set to 755. You can see a working demo of this here: http://pixelcakecreative.com/grids/

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks in advance

Comment: What webserver are you using?

Comment: By the look of the server response, it's a GFE 2.0 server, so quite possible that an Apache-specific function won't be available

Comment: yes, it seems that way. Doesnt look like its supported on this list: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/hardware-software/apache-modules-that-are-on-all-of-our-shared-servers    bummer

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

> This function is an alias for apache_request_headers(). Please read the apache_request_headers() documentation for more information on how this function works.

If you're not using apache (with php as a module), this function is not available.

Comment: it is on a shared hosting environment, I do not have access to these settings. I would assume shared hosting would allow for this.

Comment: They're probably running PHP prior to version 5.4 as something other than an Apache module (FastCGI for example). That or they're using something other than Apache (nginx, etc)

Comment: can this be added to shared hosting environments or would I need dedicated?

Answer (score 0):

It's an [apache related function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.apache.php). Maybe You don't have needed extensions installed?

Answer (score 0):

from the hosting company:  It appears that that function is only supported when PHP is run as an Apache module. Our Shared and Reseller servers run PHP as CGI, and unfortunately this cannot be changed. We apologize for any inconvenience.

If that function is absolutely required for your site, you will need to consider upgrading to a VPS, in which case PHP can be installed however you like.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to be sure you have such a function not depending on server software configuration:

```
if (!function_exists("getallheaders"))
{
  function getallheaders()
  {
    $headers = "";

    foreach ($_SERVER as $name => $value)
    {
      if (substr($name, 0, 5) == "HTTP_")
      {
        $headers[str_replace(" ", "-", ucwords(strtolower(str_replace("_", " ", substr($name, 5)))))] = $value;
      }
    }

    return $headers;
  }
}
```